# Removing folder in Github repository gives "fatal: pathspec did not match any files"

Tags: git

I have a Github repo and want to delete one of the folders in it

I tried `git rm -r [folder_name]` and got:

```
fatal: pathspec '[folder_name]' did not match any files
```

I then tried `git remote update` and `git fetch` and they both seemed ok.   I then tried `git checkout --track origin/master` and got

```
 fatal: A branch named 'master' already exists.
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Those two commands (`git rm -r [folder_name]` and `git checkout --track origin/master`) don't seem to have anything to do with each other. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to remove `folder_name` from the github repo. I only tried `git checkout --track origin/master` because I saw it mentioned in another stackoverflow question

Comment: Are you sure the folder is being tracked by git? If you run `rm -r [folder_name]` and then run `git status`, under which heading do you see the folder's files?

Comment: I don't see the folder's files at all after running `git status`